# QGIS with a Bentley Microstation database

Tags: qgis, bentley

Database adjacent and GIS virgin asking. How can I get started?

Most users are using Bentley Microstation for their tasks but for some reason one of the users that has a slightly different task is being moved to QGIS. I'm beginning to understand the Microstation database but I can't see that QGIS can read and write from the same database. Is this next to impossible with a team of programmers or is there a module, plugin or some application that can do this for us?

Comment: I fear that GDAL can communicate with Microstation only through the design files (dgn) https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dgn.html and read/wrote access requires Teigha libraries and all that feels complicated. Maybe you can find some other file format that is understood by both QGIS and MicroStation.

Comment: We moved from MicroStation to Oracle - we needed to use an ETL to move the data. It was a large task. I don't think the time or effort for a plugin for QGIS is ever going to happen.